# have a field not_analyzed in elasticsearch for kibana

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana

Apparently my cidr values are being processed in such a way that in a terms table panel the values appear missing.

To fix that, I used the following to edit the mapping. mongoindex being the index's name and mongodb being the river's name:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/mongoindex/mongodb/_mapping' -d '
{
"mongodb" : {
"properties" : {
"cidr" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
}
}
}'
```

And I got

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

However, the cidr values are still the same ie only showing a part in the terms table. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mappings are set when an index is created.  You have three choices:

1. reindex your documents
2. wait for logstash to create a new index tomorrow
3. delete today's index (losing your data) and let logstash create a new index now.

Also note that since everyone experiences this problem, logstash creates a ".raw" version of each field, which is not analyzed.  Try using cidr.raw in your panel.

Comment: I'm not using Logstash. Im indexing from MongoDB using the River plugin. In case I want to reindex my data, could you kindly show me the proper way to include the mapping settings in my new index? Thank you.

Comment: If you have daily indexes (helps with management), then the comments are the same.  Elasticsearch provides a guide to reindexing: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html